# Ubuntu 22.04 - Loginscreen accepts no Input

Tags: login

When booting, Ubuntu is "stuck" at this screen:
[image: Ubuntu Login Screen]
The mouse does not move, the keyboard does not react, the keyboard itself seems to be "stuck" too, as Capslock and Num for example do not trigger the leds on the keyboard.

The clock however still works and after a few minutes, the screen gradually goes into sleep mode, so it is not completely frozen.

Things I tried so far:

- in recovery mode, did numerous update / upgrade stuff, there are no errors, however, keyboard works perfectly fine here
- booted the previous kernel, same result
- attached different keyboard / mouse
- downgraded Nvidia Driver to 520 (from 525)
- Enabled Autologin via `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- tried to connect via RDP:
  [image: RDP Fail]

Does anyone have an idea, what can cause this?

Any help highly appreciated.

//EDIT Downgraded Nvidia to 520, same result

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured rdp I sometimes it can give those issues, if you can, start in fail safe mode or just ssh to the machine and run sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all