# Mouse and keyboard not working on Ubuntu 22.04 fresh installation on Windows Surface

Tags: boot, keyboard, 22.04, touchpad, surface

I'm trying to run Ubuntu off a USB, but I get stuck on the "Welcome, Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu" screen. The keyboard, track pad, and touch screen are all not responsive. The caps lock LED does not turn on, however the 'fn' LED does. The backlights do turn on when any key is pressed.

Most tutorials/answers elsewhere give you solutions for restoring your keyboard when the mouse is working or the mouse when the keyboard is working. I obviously can't do either of those things. My solutions must be limited to UEFI or the grub bootloader screen.

Possibly related: I couldn't get into the first screen at all unless I chose the "safe graphics" option in the GRUB screen. Both these symptoms were present when I attempted to install Fedora as well.

Here's what I've read:

- [Ubuntu 22.04 - Login screen accepts no Input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444669/ubuntu-22-04-loginscreen-accepts-no-input) seems similar, but I'm on a fresh install and it has nothing to do with RDP.
- [Ubuntu freezes after booting from USB drive on 2020 Macbook Air](https://askubuntu.com/q/1393612/) This is exactly my problem, but different hardware. It worries me that their answer is "yeah it's not going to work".
- [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Keyboard and Mouse not Working](https://appuals.com/fix-ubuntu-20-04-lts-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working)  This site on "case 3" is the closest I've gotten to a helpful solution. The problem is, it's for an older version of Ubuntu. When he says "Insert `/bin/bash` before $vt_handoff and press Ctrl + X", only there is no $vt_handoff on the command I'm editing. When I try to add `/bin/bash` to various places in the command, it doesn't open a prompt when I run it.

I can get into a terminal from the grub screen, but then I can't use apt to install the various things the tutorial requires.

How do I get my mouse and keyboard working?

Comment: I got some help from my coworker. We discovered a USB mouse works. I can't reference all the sites he found, but apparently Microsoft surfaces have proprietary keyboards and track pads. I would need a custom kernal to get the keyboard and track pad working. That amount of effort isn't worth it to me. Buyers beware! Microsoft surfaces are garbage. If anyone wants to solve this problem for others, go for it! If not, I'm willing to let this question die.